# Academic regression tables in the tidymodels workflow?

Tags: r, regression, stargazer, tidymodels, modelsummary

Is there any way to create a `stargazer::stargazer()` style (or something close to it) coef table using a `broom::tidy()` object? I have tried `gt()` but it doesn't seem tailored for publication-ready LaTeX/Rmd tables.

Comment: Where is the MCVE?

Comment: Perhaps closer: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`modelsummary` package is compatible](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) with `broom`. It produces highly-customizable `stargazer`-style regression tables (and more!), which can be saved to many formats such as HTML, LaTeX, or Word. (Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

You can summarize models side-by-side as in `stargazer` by storing them in a list. Under the hood, `modelsummary` will use `broom` to extract coefficients and such:

```r
library(modelsummary)
mod <- list(
    lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars),
    lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars))

modelsummary(mod)
```

[image]

If you want to work from raw `broom::tidy` object, you can also do it by creating a named list of class `modelsummary_list`. This second option allows you to use the default `broom` output, or to modify the `broom` output manually, or to create your own.

Example:

```
mod <- list(
    tidy = broom::tidy(mod),
    glance = broom::glance(mod))
class(mod) <- c("modelsummary_list", class(mod))

modelsummary(mod)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I'm trying out your package now. One question: is it possible to efficiently summarize nested models in modelsummary? For example code see @EmilHvitfeldt's answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777221/augmenting-coxph-output-in-a-tidymodels-workflow

I know I could achieve a similar result by filtering based on the nested variable and estimating models separately inside list(), but suspect there is a cleaner way to estimate and present the models.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl) %>% mutate(models = list(lm(mpg~hp, data = data))) %>% pull(models) %>% modelsummary`

Comment: Yes! This is actually a more efficient strategy for estimating the models than what I was doing before, and outputting into a nice table by default is really nice for quickly interpreting results. Much appreciation, I am going to be evangelizing this package to all the R users in my department.

One final question: is it possible to automatically name the models based on the values of the variable in `nest_by()`?

Comment: Cool. If you pass a *named* list to `modelsummary`, the names will be used as column headers. The `pull` function accepts a `name` argument that assigns names to the elements of the column you are pulling. So in my example you could just swap the `pull` call for: `pull(models, name = cyl)`